# Melhor prática direcionamento action result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Necessito direcionar o **administrador** para um local, o **aluno com primeiro acesso** para outro e o **aluno que já acessou**, para outro.

Minhas validações estão funcionando, tudo está dando certinho. Porém, gostaria de saber se há uma melhor prática a aplicar para tal:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Validar(String cpf, String senha)
        {
            var bdAluno = CONSUL_CA_AlunoAplicacaoConstrutor.CONSUL_CA_AlunoAplicacaoEF();
            var alunos = bdAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Senha == senha);
            if (alunos.Count() == 1)
            {
                var aluno = alunos.First();

                if (aluno.Cpf == "1413914")
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("admin", false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeADM", new { area = "Administrador" });
                }

                else if (aluno.Senha == "sbe123") {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(aluno.Cpf, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("AlterarSenha", "HomeAL", new { area = "Aluno" });

                }
                else { 
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(aluno.Cpf, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeAL", new { area = "Aluno" });
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O redirecionamento *per si* está ok, mas com certeza a maneira com que as decisões são tomadas para que esses redirecionamentos sejam feitos precisa de uma boa refatoração.

Primeiro a seguinte linha pode encontrar alunos que tenham a mesma senha assim fazendo que alguns alunos podessem ser logar com o CPF outros alunos por acidente:

```
var alunos = bdAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Senha == senha);
// Deve ficar
var alunos = bdAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x =>x.Cpf == cpf && x.Senha == senha);
```

Também não é boa prática colocar dados *hardcoded* no seu código como por exemplo nestas linhas:

```cs
if (aluno.Cpf == "1413914")
//e
if (aluno.Senha == "sbe123")
```

Indique quem são administradores e alunos novatos na própria classe aluno:

```cs
class Aluno {
    public String Cpf {get;set;}
    public String Senha {get;set;}
    public boolean JaAcessouOSistema {get;set;}
    public boolean Administrador {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult Validar(String cpf, String senha)
    {
        var bdAluno = CONSUL_CA_AlunoAplicacaoConstrutor.CONSUL_CA_AlunoAplicacaoEF();
        var alunos = bdAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Cpf == cpf x.Senha == senha);
        if (alunos.Count() == 1)
        {
            var aluno = alunos.First();

            if (aluno.Administrador)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("admin", false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeADM", new { area = "Administrador" });
            }

            else if (!aluno.JaAcessouOSistema) {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(aluno.Cpf, false);
                return RedirectToAction("AlterarSenha", "HomeAL", new { area = "Aluno" });

            }
            else { 
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(aluno.Cpf, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeAL", new { area = "Aluno" });
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Outras boas práticas seriam a utilização da arquitetura em 3 camadas (não somente o MVC e sim o camada de apresentação, negócios e acesso a dados), [IoC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invers%C3%A3o_de_controle) e tratar o caso do usuário não ser encontrado no sistema.